# headless linux server for web serving tasks

Tags: headless, containers, lightweight

I only need to run text-based applications on my server.  think LAMP + ssh.  It seems unnecessary to install entire distributions, like ubuntu, just to fire up apache and serve up my one web app.  instead, it would be nice to have a more lightweight distro that runs easily in a container (lxc docker) as well as on my old hardware as well as a virtual machine as well as ...

does this kind of "light text-based server distro" exist anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/) is what you're looking for. It's a new-ish linux distro, targeted at providing a bare minimum OS for docker deployments.

Alternatively, just install Debian or even Ubuntu's Server distribution. Either are quite lightweight.

Comment: unfortunately, CoreOS does not seem to have a bare-metal version.  it relies on vagrant, which in turn seems to rely on an installed OS.

Comment: @ivoWelch - Incorrect. You missed the [Installing to Disk](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/installing-to-disk/) section.

Comment: thx for pointing this out.  you are correct.  the quickstart guide that the site pointed me to had not even mentioned it.  but I see it now elsewhere.  installing-to-disk still seems a little raw.  let's say I have a completely fresh server.  I need a USB stick or ISO file to boot from (minor), and this needs to set up grub[2].  I only see partition setup instructions.  or did I miss this, too?